# How to change the attribute value based on the count of value in XML file using XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have the below sample XML file and I just need to change the testng-results tag values like passed, Failed, skipped based on the "status" value in the XML

**Sample input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <testng-results skipped="0" failed="0" total="10" passed="10">
    <test-method status="FAIL" is-config="true" duration-ms="4"
        started-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z">
        <params>
            <param index="0">
                <value>                <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                </value>
            </param>
        </params>
        <reporter-output>
        </reporter-output>
     </test-method> <!-- setParameter -->
      <test-method status="PASS" is-config="true" duration-ms="4"
        started-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z">
        <params>
            <param index="0">
                <value>                <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                </value>
            </param>
        </params>
        <reporter-output>
        </reporter-output>
     </test-method> <!-- setParameter -->
      <test-method status="SKIPPED" is-config="true" duration-ms="4"
        started-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z" finished-at="2018-08-16T21:43:38Z">
        <params>
            <param index="0">
                <value>                <![CDATA[org.testng.TestRunner@31c2affc]]>
                </value>
            </param>
        </params>
        <reporter-output>
        </reporter-output>
     </test-method> <!-- setParameter -->
  </testng-results>
```

For the above example We have one PASS, FAIL and SKIPPED status (). First we need to get the count of PASS, FAIL, SKIPPED in the input XML file
  And change the values in testng-results tag accordingly. And the output for the above payload  tag value should be updated as look like below:

```
 <testng-results skipped="1" failed="1" total="3" passed="1">
```

"total" is the status of all.

Is this possible to achieve this by using XSLT?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you have an actual question, or are you just looking for someone to do your work for you?

Comment: Its sample data but I want to make changes based on another XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use :

```
<testng-results skipped="{count(//test-method/@status='SKIPPED')}" failed="{count(//test-method/@status='FAIL')}" total="{count(//test-method)}" passed="{count(//test-method/@status='PASS')}">
```

Comment: Is this Sample XSLT?

Comment: While asking the question you please post your try also which will help us to answer easily and focus on your exact problem...